# Linux kernel code seems to ignore caching

Tags: c, exception, caching, linux-kernel, kernel

From [Understanding the Linux Kernel 3rd edition](http://gauss.ececs.uc.edu/Courses/e4022/code/memory/understanding.pdf) , chapter 10.4.4, which discussing about page fault exception while the Kernel accessing user space memory:

> the Page Fault handler do_page_fault( ) executes the following
> statements:

```
 if ((fixup = search_exception_tables(regs->eip))) {
 regs->eip = fixup->fixup;
 return 1;
 }
```

> The regs->eip field contains the value of the eip register saved on
> the Kernel Mode stack **when the exception occurred**. If the value in the
> register (the instruction pointer) is in an exception table,
> do_page_fault( ) replaces the saved value with the address found in
> the entry returned by search_exception_tables( ). Then the Page Fault
> handler terminates and the interrupted program resumes with execution
> of the fixup code .

Well understood, beside a crucial fact- memory operations can be **cached**, which means that at the moment of the page fault exception, the instruction pointer contained address of another instruction which had no relation to the exception, as the instruction that caused the exception executed earlier by the CPU but was cached up until this moment (reference to that in [here](https://www.freertos.org/Debugging-Hard-Faults-On-Cortex-M-Microcontrollers.html) at last paragraphs).

How can Linux Kernel execute the above code with no side effects? how can it be sure that at the time of the page fault exception, the instruction pointer register contained the address of the memory-operation instruction (that can be **cached** and performed later on) that accessed illegal address?

**EDIT #1:**
I believe the same guide has a hint in chapter 2.4.7-

> the cache unit is inserted between the paging unit and the main memory

Maybe it implies that address translation and checking in always done **prior** (or during) to caching (at least in x86 architecture, in which the guide is based on) which can explain my issue by the fact that address check in done in the MMU circuitry **at the moment of instruction execution**? unfortunately I could not find any definitive 'Yes' in the guide nor in my searches online.

**EDIT #2:**
I found another source in [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/745008/whats-the-difference-between-physical-and-virtual-cache) that strengthen my speculation in EDIT #1:

> Permissions still need to be checked before the access can be
> committed

So, it seems (without any confirmation from formal source) that upon memory access, the address goes into MMU circuitry for translation before or during the caching, which means that address check is done at instruction execution time, and that this is the moment when page fault can be raised. So the cache latency of main memory access is irrelevant to the page fault timing, and when page fault occurs, instruction pointer register indeed contains the faulty instruction which tries to access invalid address. I'll keep searching for a source that confirms that, or alternatively a source that contradict that and that offers a proper solution.

Comment: When user space caused a page fault, it was executing a particular instruction and trying to access a certain address - why would caching of any kind (are you talking about the l1/l2/l3 cache ? ) impact this ?

Comment: Regarding saving the instruction pointer address at exception moment - `if writes to memory are cached then there might be a delay between an assembly instruction initiating a write to memory and the write to memory actually occurring. If such a delayed write operation is invalid (for example, a write is being attempted to an invalid memory location) ... the program counter value obtained will not be the address of the assembly instruction that initiated the write operation.` (taken from https://www.freertos.org/Debugging-Hard-Faults-On-Cortex-M-Microcontrollers.html) well known concept

Comment: @nos also the page fault exception in the chapter takes place in kernel mode, which tries to access memory addresses passed by the user mode

Comment: Yes, and for that to work properly the kernel can't have userspace generating imprecise exceptions - the CPU must have full control of the memory locations referenced by user space - I suspect this is mostly an issue on CPUs not containing an MMU (which isn't really supported by linux), or when executing kernel code - in which case you're usually hosed anyway by such an exception.

Comment: @nos I'm trying to understand from your comment how the Linux kernel can make sure instruction pointer register points to faulty instruction at exception time. Only way to accomplish that (as I see it) is by forcing the CPU to wait until memory operation is being performed. If I'm missing something, please post an answer with your full explanation so I could see what i'm missing, and I'll happily accept it as an answer

Comment: No, I don't know enough to make a full answer - other than a CPU having an MMU have to perform the neccesary checks that the address is valid according to the current page table entries when the instruction is executed, not when the actual memory access is happending. (And if an additional exception occurs when the actual write happens, that would rather indicate a severe hardware fault, not just simply that the process tried to write to invalid memory)

Comment: @nos `CPU having an MMU have to perform the neccesary checks that the address is valid according to the current page table entries when the instruction is executed, not when the actual memory access is happending` - if you can find a reference point to that, some document, I'll accept that as an answer

Comment: Take a look how the regs structure is filled - probably there you will find the answer